# Loop across rows and colums with nested data

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I have the following data structure: Meetings in Persons in Groups. The groups met differently often and the number of group members varied for every meeting.

```
 $ GroupID                    : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ groupnames                 : chr  "A&M" "A&M" "A&M" "A&M" ...
 $ MeetiID                    : chr  "1" "1" "2" "2" ...
 $ Date_Meetings              : chr  "43293" "43293" "43298" "43298" ...
 $ PersonID                   : num  171 185 171 185 185 113 135 113 135 113 ...
 $ v_165                      : chr  "3" "3" "4" "3" ...
 $ v_166                      : chr  "2" "2" "3" "3" ...
 $ v_167                      : chr  "2" "4" "4" "3" ...
 $ v_168                      : chr  "6" "7" "4" "5" ...
 $ problemtypes_categories: chr  "Knowledgeproblem" "Knowledgeproblem" "Motivationalproblem" "Coordinationproblem" ...
 $ v_165_dicho                : num  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ v_166_dicho                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ v_167_dicho                : num  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Now I have to create a new variable that should be binary (0/1) with the name agreement_levels. So, every time, a person in one group has - regarding the same learning meeting - a same problem type category than the other learner(s) of the same group at the same meeting, both learners (or three or four, depending on the group size for a respective meeting) should get the value 1 at the agreement variable, else they should all get 0. Whenever a person (e.g., among four learners) already has a different category of problem than the others, there is a 0 on the agreement variable for all.
If only 1 person is in the data set for one and the same meeting, there must be a NA at agree. When one person has NA at the problemtype variable, however, and there are 2 people in the data set for the same meeting, both get 0 at agree; but if there are 4 people for the same meeting in the data set and one of them has NA at problemtype, then only this person but not the others get NA at agree.

I did already write a command, but it is not working yet and still does not consider the NAs:

```
 GroupID1 <- df$GroupID[1:nrow,]
                         TreffID1 <- df$TreffID[1:nrow,]
                         for(i in 1:(GroupID1 -1){
                           for(j in 1:(TreffID1 -1){
                             if(df[i, 3] == df[i+1, 3]-1){
                                  if(df[i, 15] == df[i+1, 15]-1){
                                      df[c(i, i+1), 28] <- 1,
                                      df[c(i, i+1), 28] <- 0
```

Many thanks in advance.

```
dput(head(df))
structure(list(GroupID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2"), TreffID = c("1", "1", 
"2", "2", "3", "1"), PersonID = c(171, 185, 171, 185, 
185, 113), problemtypen_oberkategorien = c("Verständnisprobleme", 
"Verständnisprobleme", "Motivationsprobleme", "Motivationsprobleme", 
"Motivationsprobleme", "Motivationsprobleme"), passung.exkl = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: it would help if you provided some sample data. try using dput(head(df)) and pasting the results.

Comment: Thank you. Now, I had to post the data with german variable names. problemtypen_oberkategorien is the problemtype variable and TreffID is the MeetingID

Comment: What are the relevant variables in your data example? I'm pretty sure open ended questions like `v_164` are irrelevant. Please restrict your example to relevant variables only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loops, I used R's `dplyr`. I'm not sure if I got all your logic correct, since there was a lot there. For example, you didn't specify what would happen for NA problemtype and 3 people. But here is a starting point that uses `group_by`, so you are looking within each set of rows with the same GroupID and TreffID, and then `mutate` and `case_when`, which assign values to a new column, according to criteria, and then functions like `n()` that count how many rows and `n_distinct` that count distinct rows so you if it is ==1 then we know they are all the same.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    df <- df %>% 
      group_by(GroupID, TreffID) %>% 
      mutate(agreement_levels = case_when(n() == 1 ~ -1,
                                          is.na(problemtypen_oberkategorien) & n() == 2 ~ 0,
                                          is.na(problemtypen_oberkategorien) & n() > 2 ~ -1,
                                          n_distinct(problemtypen_oberkategorien, na.rm = FALSE) == 1 ~ 1,
                                          n_distinct(problemtypen_oberkategorien, na.rm = FALSE) > 1 ~ 0,
                                          TRUE ~ -1),
             agreement_levels = na_if(agreement_levels, -1)) %>%
      select(GroupID, TreffID, problemtypen_oberkategorien, agreement_levels, everything())
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I want to calculate if the group members faced the same kind of problem during one meeting, in case that one of three members has NA at problemtype, the other 2 could still agree. But if two of them have NA at problemtype, all three members must get the NA at agree because there is no chance anymore then to calculate an agreement.

Comment: ok i changed the third criteria is.na(problemtype) & n() == 4 to n() > 2 .

Comment: Thank you, I know this question might sound stupid but could you also tell me how I can integrate the new variable into my dataframe df and also, how I can reach that the agree variabl only differentiates between NA, 0, and 1 (but not TRUE or FALSE)?

Comment: the variable is already in the data frame. df$agreement_levels

Comment: The case_when didn't let me put numerics 1 0 and NAs together. Can you work with TRUE and FALSE instead of 1 and 0 ?

Comment: But only under your command in the console. So, I cannot view my df and see the new variable and I can also not call the new variable by using df$agreement_levels. Actually I need the 0 and 1, but you anyway helped me a lot, thanks again!

Comment: Can you use -1 instead of NA? then you can switch to 1, 0, -1

Comment: ok I found a function that will generate NAs after we make them -1. see revised answer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the last NA. fixed now